# Hermitian Pairings from Positive Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, bilinear-form

Let $A$ be $*$-algebra and $\phi:A \to {\mathbb C}$ a *positive* linear functional, that is, one for which $\phi(aa^*) \geq 0$, for all $a \in A$. When does it hold that a symmetric sesquilinear form, i.e. a Hermitian form, is given by
$$
A \times A \to {\mathbb C}, ~~~~~~ (a,b) \mapsto \phi(ab^*).
$$
(Note that I am not assuming any completeness here, despite the tags.)

Comment: Hemritian or Hermitian ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "symmetric sesquilinear pairing"? I cannot really understand what you are asking.

Comment: If I get it right, you really want to know if $\phi(x^\ast)=\overline{\phi(x)}$, don't you?

Comment: @Martin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form

Comment: @Mao: Yes, this is what I would like to know. But I am now guessing that I need to make some type of completeness assumption to get this . . .

Comment: @Lars: thanks. I have never seen "symmetric sesquilinear" in the real world. I have always seen just "sesquilinear". But I guess it makes sense because one might want to distinguish the property $\langle a,b\rangle=\overline{\langle b,a\rangle}$.

Comment: @MaoWao,Lars the condition $\phi(x^*) = \overline{\phi(x)}$ should follow now from the answer below.

Comment: . . . and so that the given definition makes a Hermitian form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the start make note:
$$
\mathbb{R} \ni \phi((a+1)(a+1)^*) = \phi(aa^*)+\phi(a)+\phi(a^*)+ 1.
$$
Next on, since $\phi(aa^*) \in {\mathbb R}$, we must have $\phi(a)+\phi(a^*) \in \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $\Im(\phi(a)) = - \Im(\phi(a^*))$. Do the same trick for $ia$:
$$
\mathbb{R} \ni \phi((ia+1)(ia+1)^*) = \phi(aa^*)+i\phi(a) - i\phi(a^*)+ 1 \\
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=  \phi(aa^*) + 1 + i(\phi(a) - \phi(a^*)).
$$
Hence, we have got
$$
\Re(\phi(a)) = \Re(\phi(a^*)).
$$
We must have at the last
$$
\phi(a^*) = \overline{\phi(a)}.
$$

Comment: Of course, this proof does not work if $A$ doesn't have a unit. In the non-unital setting, you have to require that $A^2 = A$.